# Как правильно расширить класс?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь расширить класс `Array` при помощи `prototype`, добавив в него свой метод, но при обходе массива циклом созданный метод видится элементом массива:

```
Array.prototype.fun = (function() {
})();

var arr = [1, 2];

for (var i in arr) {
    alert(i);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phojh6qk/

Я что-то делаю неправильно?

Comment: на самом деле просто не надо было использовать `for..in`

Comment: вы перебираете массив методом перебора объекта, а массив перебирается так 

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `defineProperty` позволяет задать такие параметры, в том числе, и `enumerable` - чтобы созданное свойство не было видно при обходе массива циклом:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'fun', {
    value: function() {
    }
});
```

По умолчанию, значение `enumerable` установлено в `false`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty